# Travel to Cuba directly as Canadian from Boston Logan

Tags: visas, air-travel, canadian-citizens, cuba

My American friend bought herself and me a ticket to fly to Cuba in a month from Boston Logan to Fort Lauderdale to Havana. As a Canadian, what steps do I have to take visa-wise? (In particular, how do I obtain a tourist card?)

Comment: For travel to the US, under normal circumstances, Canadians do not need a visa.  Furthermore, because they enjoy this state of affairs independently of the visa waiver program, they don't need (and cannot get) ESTA approval.  So, unless there are circumstances you have not disclosed, such as a criminal history, your question really boils down to "what are the entry requirements for a Canadian citizen in Cuba."  For that you'll need a tourist card, and this is a comment rather than an answer because I do not know the details for that.

Answer (score 4):

You are buying the Cuban Tourist Card at the "gateway airport" (the final airport before departing the U.S.) and it costs $50 per person. All you  need is your passport, boarding pass (doh!) and typically a credit card.

This is the relevant [JetBlue](https://www.jetblue.com/flights/cuba/) page which I very strongly suspect you are flying.